# Using apache cxf to dynamicly create web service client (fix no operation found unchecked exception), invoke operation with authentication

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

So I wanted to to find a way to invoke web service operation dynamically with authentication.

This is what I found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for how to create dynamic web service client with apache cxf, avoid the "no operation found for name" unchecked exception and use authentication.

```
    DynamicClientFactory dcf = DynamicClientFactory.newInstance();
    Client client = dcf.createClient("WSDL Location");

    AuthorizationPolicy authorization = ((HTTPConduit) client.getConduit()).getAuthorization();

    authorization.setUserName(
            "user name"
    );

    authorization.setPassword(
            "password"
    );

    Object[] res = client.invoke(new QName("http://targetNameSpace/", "operationName"), params...);
    System.out.println("Echo response: " + res[0]);
```

the new QName with the name space fixed the exception.

Enjoy.

Comment: If you are using cxf only for the dynamic client here is the list of jars you need: commons-logging-1.1, cxf-2.7.4, cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.4, httpasyncclient-4.0-beta3, httpclient-4.2.1, httpcore-4.2.2, httpcore-nio-4.2.2, neethi-3.0.2, stax2-api-3.1.1, woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0, wsdl4j-1.6.3, xmlschema-core-2.0.3